# Create a Single Thread Executor that has priority based queuing/exeuting

Tags: java, concurrency

I am wanting to develop a game where it uses an executor single thread.

I have 3 types of tasks that need to be created:

1. Soft task
2. Normal task
3. Hard task

A soft task is the least priority when waiting in the queue, normal is next and hard is the highest priority.

When a normal task is inside the queue, it should execute over the soft task, but the soft task should not be removed.

When a hard task is inside the queue / pushed onto it, it should remove all soft and normal tasks from the queue.

When a hard task is executing, it should block the thread until an action from the player is performed (such as click to continue).

I am wondering what executor I should use or queues i should use to create this single thread for an event loop style game? Any suggestions would be appreciated. I couldn't find an example online/understand it for my scenario.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! This site isn't about general programming and languages, but is rather focused on Salesforce (a cloud-based Customer Relationship Management platform). As such, this is not on topic for this site. [so] is probably where you meant to go instead.

Comment: @DerekF And it's opinion-based. Please don't migrate bad posts

Answer (score 0):

A single thread executor is enough for you, but you would probably want to implement your own queue as normal queues certainly can not satisfy you here.

I would use a heap to implement the queue, to make sure that higher priority tasks run before lower priority tasks. The heap should be cleared when a Hard Task arrives.

You can also imlement a queue that contains three lists. Soft Task list, Normal Task list, Hard Task list. The queue first checks the Hard Task list to execute, then normal, then soft. Soft Task list and Nomal Task lists are cleared when a Hard Task arrives.